# CIrcular gradient with fading effect

Tags: css, sass

I am trying recreate the shadowy effect around the text from this [Dribbble](https://dribbble.com/shots/17642120-SaaS-landing-Page-Online-Video-Editor/attachments/12796071?mode=media).  here is [Image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9blhP.png)
I tried using radial gradient background on circular button with box shadow, but unable to achieve same effect.

Following is my css code:

```
    button {
          background: radial-gradient(#ccdaf4, #dbe5f4,#f9fbff);
          box-shadow: 7px 7px 40px #f9fbff;
          width: 3rem;
          height:3rem;
          border:none;
          border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

The problem is there is either sharp boundary between box shadow and border of button or box shadow is not vissible, What I am doing wrong?